# Ansible & Jenkins

Tags: ansible, jenkins, ansible-playbook

here is my problem

I run a playbook on jenkins with extra variables, I want to test in my playbook is variables are defined

ansible [core 2.12.1] , jenkins plugin 1.1

here is the command from jenkins :

ansible-playbook create_user.yml -i hosts -e Site=UK -e BU=Test -e date_exp=

my code for testing is below

```
- name: Set expiration date 
  when : not date_exp
  set_fact:
   date_exp: "01/01/2024"

- name: Expiration date
  debug:
   msg:
    - "{{ date_exp}}"
```

tried so many things:
not , is undefined , =="" nothing works

Comment: Do you want `date_exp=` to be recognized as `False`?

Comment: false or empty, whatever

Answer (score 1):

Test the length of the string

```yaml
  when: date_exp|length == 0
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: date_exp
    - debug:
        var: date_exp|type_debug
    - debug:
        msg: var is empty
      when: date_exp|length == 0
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e date_exp=

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  date_exp: ''

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  date_exp|type_debug: str

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: var is empty

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e date_exp=xxx

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  date_exp: xxx

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  date_exp|type_debug: str

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: already tried this one too, don't work